# NSTextview subclass: binding not working

Tags: xcode, cocoa, binding, subclass, nstextview

I have a subclass of NSTextView whose "value" property is bound to a string in my CoreData model. I have set this up in IB and it works fine.

Now I want to change the binding programmatically like this:

```
[_myView bind:@"value" toObject: _myArrayController withKeyPath:@"selection.myString" options:nil];
```

This works without problem for a normal NSTextView, but not for my subclass.

So I googled around for a while but did not find a solution. Then I found this: When I check the exposed bindings of my NSTextView subclass in my appController like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[_myView exposedBindings]);
```

I get "(null)". If I put this command

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self exposedBindings]);
```

in any method inside my subclass of NSTextView, I get an array with all the available bindings, including "value". It seems like the bindings get lost at some point or I cannot access them from my appControler.

How is this possible? Any ideas?

Comment: What if you just log _myView from your app controller, does it return what you expect?

Comment: If I type NSLog(@"%@",_myView) I get (null). When I do the same for another NSTextView in my UI I get a bunch of values like frame, bounds, ... The strange thing is, that it works fine as long as I configure the binding with IB. I cannot even unbind anything programmatically. Again, if I type the equivalent inside one of the methods of my subclass, the log works.

Comment: Getting null for _myView means, either it's been deallocated (because you don't have a strong reference to it) or you haven't connected something up right in your appController. In appController, what is _myView?  Is it an IBOutlet pointing to your view, or did you alloc init an instance of you view class in the appController?

Comment: _myView is an IBOutlet pointing to my view. I have the same setup (IBOutlet) for the other NSTextView I was talking about - the one that can be logged.

Comment: Make sure that's hooked up correctly.  It shouldn't return null if it is.

Comment: D'oh! You're right, it was not hooked up properly. Thanks a lot!